# Update column in table based on another table field

Tags: sql-server

I have a prescription table that I want to set non active based upon a condition in the patient table.  Will this work?

```
 update Prescription
set active = 0
from prescription left join patients on patients.id = prescription.patientid
where patients.[site] = @site
```

I don't want to chance it yet as I have an active, production database.

Comment: Why not you use sub query?

Comment: @SandipPatel - such as?

Comment: You could wrap it inside a transaction, check your changed data sets with select and rollback at the end to proof. Transaction syntax depends on SQL-Implementation.

Comment: Why the left join instead of an inner join?

Comment: Read up on [transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188929.aspx) in SQL Server.  If you do not have a test server/database this is the next best approach.  The basic format is `BEGIN TRANSACTION    UPDATE...; SELECT...;   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`.  Remember to backup your database regularly, as sooner or later you'll forgot to rollback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple subquery:

```
UPDATE Prescription
SET active = 0 
WHERE patientid IN(SELECT id FROM patients WHERE [site] = @site)
```

**OR**

```
UPDATE Prescription
SET active = 0 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM patients p WHERE p.id=Prescription.patientid AND p.[site] = @site)
```

Comment: EXIST often better than IN